# Error while running Bash Script within landscape web UI

Tags: scripts, landscape, scp, cp

On landscape quickstart I running a simple script from the UI.

My script look like that:

```
#!/bin/bash
cp $LANDSCAPE_ATTACHMENTS /home/afadmin/Downloads/
```

I got the following error:

```
cp: omitting directory 'tmp/tmp14dbm8rn'
```

My script failed and its important to mention that i have fully access between server and client via SSH with public and private authentication .

Please advise

Answer (score 2):

One gets that error message when one asks `cp` to copy a directory. `cp` needs the `--recursive` option to copy directories, or you could

```
 cp --recursive $LANDSCAPE_ATTACHMENTS /home/afadmin/Downloads/
```

or

```
 cp $LANDSCAPE_ATTACHMENTS/* /home/afadmin/Downloads
```